# How can use onclick on different table td in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have one looping Dates and table content.

I want to display table content based on Dates. How's it possible please help me.

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @batches.each do |batch| %>
  <tr>
    **<td class = "pie"  id ="demo"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>  
      <%= batch.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if !batch.date.nil? %></td>**
    <td><%= batch.purchase_center.name.to_s  if !batch.purchase_center.nil? %></td>
    <td><%= batch.plant.name.to_s if !batch.plant.nil?%></td>
    <td><%= batch.species.name.to_s if !batch.species.nil? %></td>
    <td><%= batch.batch_number %></td>
    <td><%= batch.total_quantity %></td>
    <td><%= batch.calculated_yeild %></td>
    <td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-users"></i>'.html_safe, "#", :class => "addsupplier", :id => "#{batch.serial_id}" %></td><td><%= link_to '<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>'.html_safe, batch, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
    <tr class="<%= batch.serial_id %>" style="display:none">
        <%= render :partial => "batch_counts/form", locals: {id: "#{batch.serial_id}"} %>
    </tr>

      **<td id ="two" style="display:">
        Microsoft Corporation
        Microsoft Corporation
      </td>**

<% end %>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#demo').click(function(){
  $('#two').toggle();
});
</script>
```

I highlighted with star marks i.e. id = demo and id =two.

i have different dates and different message. So i want to display it on which date is having which message.

Based on dates display message.

Answer (score 0):

Give a common class to each of them. Say, `date-alert`:

```
<td class="pie date-alert" id="demo"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>  
  <%= batch.date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if !batch.date.nil? %></td>
```

```
<td id="two" style="display:" class="date-alert">
    Microsoft Corporation
    Microsoft Corporation
</td>
```

And then upon clicking it, you can execute like this:

```
$(".date-alert").click(function () {
  // the current td is this
});
```

Comment: It's only toggle for first one remaining are not toggle

Comment: if i click on any one of date the first id message will be toggle remaining are not toggled

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?